# Best tag - [airplane], [flight] or [flying]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 11 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) tagged [airplane](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane).

Tag wiki excerpt:

> A vehicle used for travelling long distances through the sky.

Furthermore, [flying](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying) is a synonym of [airplane](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane). This happened in April 2012, but I didn't find a meta post about it. So, now we can discuss it.

There are three possible candidates, as far as I can see:

1) [airplane](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane)

The longest and also the least inclusive, focusing on the vehicle itself. This even shows in the tag wiki excerpt, that doesn't guide the user on when to use that tag. On the plus side, it is already the master, so no change needed (except for a [new tag wiki excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/377968)).

The other two options are shorter and seem to be a bit broader, so maybe more suitable for questions also about preparations for a flight or its aftermath. On the other hand, they would need some work (but then again, it's only 11 questions).

2) [flying](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying)

Currently the tag synonym.

3) [flight](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight)

A small drawback might be to confuse it with the noun meaning to run away, but it seems unlikely.

**Keep it the way it is or do we need a change?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My preference would be for [flying](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying).

It is the least ambiguous ([flight](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight) could be confused with running away as you've cited, [airplane](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) could be misconstrued with the vehicle or possibly a toy, both of these are unlikely in my estimation).

It also succinctly conveys the intent of the tag (talking about air travel, before, during or after), whereas [airplane](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) does not.  [flight](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight) also does a good job of conveying the intent, but I feel like [flying](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flying) will be searched and found by more people (based purely on conjecture and what I feel like I would search).

Comment: This would also be more consistent, since we do have a tag [tag:driving], but no tag [car].

Comment: @AnneDaunted - Just wait for it.... "My child is afraid of riding in the..." But I agree with Becuzz.